# Sort hash by unique value

Tags: ruby

I'm using the [cinch IRC bot framework](https://github.com/cinchrb/cinch) to create an irc bot that intelligently kicks a user from the channel. In order to do that, I need to know the bot's user modes and compare it to the user's user modes. There's 4 modes that matter: q, a, o, h.

Basically: owners (q) > admins (a) > operators (o) > half-ops (h) > *. Users can have multiple usermodes. Someone can have the modes qao, but I don't care if the user is an owner and an admin, I only care that the user is an owner.

Cinch provides a hash of all known users in the channel and their usermodes. For example:

```
Users{"bot" => {"a", "o"}, "fred" => {"q", "o"}, "mike" => "o", "larry" => "v"}
```

What I'm looking to do is, as concisely as possible, take some logic that can interpret when the bot is, for example, "ao",  fred is "qo" and mike is "o" and then say "OK. I'm an admin and mike is an operator, so I can kick mike, but fred is an owner so I can't kick fred."

My idea of implementation is messy (involves a lot of if then else looping..) and I know there has to be a better way. In addition, I'm not really sure how to iterate through a key value and ignore the values at a certain point. I feel as though my idea would iterate, come across an "ao" and set as an admin, then reset as an operator which would not be what I need.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you looking for a method that takes a username and their usermodes and returns whether the bot can kick them or not, or are you looking for a method that takes a list of all usernames with their usermodes and returns a list of the users the bot can kick?

Comment: I'm looking for a method that basically compares the modes of the bot to the modes of the specified user and determines if it has the privileges to kick it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think about it like taking the "greatest" usermode the bot has and comparing it to the "greatest" usermode that the user you'd like to kick is. If the bot's is greater than or equal to the other user's, then the bot can kick the user.

In that case, you'd need a method that takes a list of usermodes and could return a numerical value corresponding to the greatest one. One implementation could be:

```
def greatest_usermode(array_of_usermodes)
  if array_of_usermodes.include?("q")
    4
  elsif array_of_usermodes.include?("a")
    3
  elsif array_of_usermodes.include?("o")
    2
  elsif array_of_usermodes.include?("h")
    1
  else 
    0
  end
end
```

Then you could define a method that just uses the mathematical `>=` operator to compare the numbers returned from this method for the bot and the user in question.

There are many other ways this could be done, but this is a pretty simple and straightforward way to do it.

Comment: that's what i was thinking of doing, but wasn't sure if there was some sort of complex sorting or something that would be considered better. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@I, @carolclarinet has the right idea, and you probably don't need any more than that.  However, I would like to mention a somewhat more elaborate way of dealing with the problem, which you might find useful in related applications.  First, suppose your hash looks like this:

```
h = {"bot" => ["a", "o"], "fred" => ["q", "o"], "mike" => ["o"], "larry" => ["h"]}
```

This is just what you have, except I've made all the single hash values arrays.  Obviously, it would be simple to get it into this form.  Below I show how you can redefine the value arrays as being instances of a new class that I've called `UserModes`, that is a subclass of `Array`.  By doing that, you can compare the value arrays in a very natural way:

```
h["bot"]                      # => ["a", "o"]
h["fred"]                     # => ["q", "o"]
h["bot"].can_kick? h["fred"]  # => false

h["mike"]                     # => ["o"]
h["bot"].can_kick? h["mike"]  # => true

h["larry"]                    # => ["h"]
h["bot"].can_kick? h["larry"] # => true

kickees[]
h.each {|k,v| kickees << k if k!="bot" && h["bot"].can_kick?(h[k])} # final () req'd
  # kickees => ["mike", "larry"]
```

If you add the other methods:

```
h["bot"] < h["fred"]   # => true
h["bot"] >= h["fred"]  # => false

h["bot"] == h["mike"]  # => false
h["bot"] > h["mike"]   # => true

h["bot"] <= h["larry"] # => false
h["bot"] >= h["larry"] # => true
```

Here's the class definition:

```
class UserModes < Array

  # Change > to >= in in can_kick? if I've misunderstood the kicking rule
  def can_kick?(other) rating(self) > rating(other) end

  # Add any or all of the following if useful to you: 
  def <=>(other) rating(self) <=> rating(other) end
  def ==(other)  rating(self) ==  rating(other) end
  def <(other)   rating(self) <   rating(other) end
  def >(other)   rating(self) >   rating(other) end
  def <=(other)  rating(self) <=  rating(other) end
  def >=(other)  rating(self) >=  rating(other) end

  private

  def rating a
    case
    when (a.include? ?q) then 3
    when (a.include? ?a) then 2
    when (a.include? ?o) then 1
    when (a.include? ?v) then 0
    else
      # raise exception
    end
  end
end
```

You see that all the public methods make use of the private method `rating`, which converts an array to a numeric score, along the lines of @carolclarinet's answer.  You can convert each hash value from an instance of `Array` to an instance of `UserModes` like this:

```
h.each_key {|k| h[k] = UserModes.new(h[k])}
```

We can confirm this works as intended:

```
h["fred"].class => UserModes
```

You can treat the values `h` as ordinary arrays, but you now also have the method `can_kick?` and, if you want, several others.  Some of those (`< <= >= >`) are not defined for `Array` objects; others (`<=> ==`) must be defined to override methods of the same name in `Array`.

Comment: that's pretty brilliant. let me ask you, how would it react if, say, the modes are listed as "o", "q"? I'm thinking it would still be marked as a 3, as that's the first case. Right?

Comment: @ILoveYou too. Yes, because the case statements are executed in turn and only until a true result is obtained. I made a few changes to my answer.  You may only need one `UserModes` instance method: `can_kick?`